# "Loops" of adjoint functors

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors

There are various naturally occuring chains of adjoint functors, e.g. between the category of simple graphs (with suitable class of morphisms) and **Set**, the functor $\pi_0$, sending a graph to its set of connected components, is left adjoint to the functor that forms the discrete graph on a set. This functor in turn is left adjoint to the forgetful functor, which itself is left adjoint to the functor that forms the complete graph on a set. This chain of length four cannot be continued on either side, but there are constructions of such chains of any finite length. (However, I do not know if there is a non-trivial (one- or two-sided) infinite chain.)

My question now is: Is it possible that such a chain forms a non-trivial loop? (By non-trivial, I mean a chain that does not come from either an adjoint equivalence or a self-adjoint functor.) For concreteness' sake, is there a nontrivial adjoint "triangle", i.e. three endofunctors $F,G,H$ on a category $\mathcal{C}$ such that $F$ is left adjoint to $G$, which is left adjoint to $H$, which again is left adjoint to $F$, without any two of these functors being isomorphic?

Thanks in advance for any information on this matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The simplest instance of this, in which we have $F \dashv G$ and $G \dashv F$, is called an [ambidextrous adjunction](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ambidextrous+adjunction) and there are many examples (for instance, [coincident limits and colimits](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/biproduct)).

The general question is tackled in Booth's [Sequences of adjoint functors](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01304920), in which he proves that cyclic adjoint changes of length $n$ exists for every positive integer $n$.

For a family of examples that arise in practice (for $n > 2$), on p. 17 of [Dualities and adjunctions of stable derivators](http://www2.math.uni-wuppertal.de/%7Ebeckert/Diplomarbeit_Falk_Beckert.pdf) Beckert gives an example of a family of infinite chains of adjunctions that have period $4n + 2$ for every natural number $n$.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know of  any longer loops, perhaps for the triangle situation I specified in the question?

Comment: @TimSeifert: I added a longer example, but unfortunately I can't think of an example of the length you asked for yet.

Comment: Nonetheless very interesting, thank you.

Comment: @TimSeifert: I have since found a reference that gives a positive answer to your original question, and edited my answer to include it.